# eli5 and SHAP for interpreting XGBoost results

Tags: xgboost, shap, eli5, xgbregressor

I have used XGBoost algorithm tried both eli5 and SHAP to interpret the results of the regression. I got some contradictory results, screenshots below.

[image: SHAP] and [image: eli5]

I do not entirely understand the difference between eli5 and SHAP and I would like to find out  which interpretation to rely more on. I would appreciate suggestions and insights into that.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably impossible to say that one is more reliable than the other; it depends on what you're looking for.  You could ask over at stats.SE or datascience.SE for some more detail about how `eli5` and `shap` produce their valuations.  [It appears that](https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries/xgboost.html) `eli5.show_weights` is just delegating to xgboost's internal feature importances based on gain (by default), weight, or cover.

All that said, these aren't contradictory.  Both the `shap` plot and the `eli5` weights suggest that `chassis_1` is the more important variable: it has larger (in absolute values) shap values as well as a higher importance score.